# Laravel sendgrid mail not sending

Tags: laravel, email, smtp, sendgrid

I'm using sendgrid for sending mails in Laravel in my .env file I have this:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_USERNAME=my-api-key-username
MAIL_PASSWORD=my-api-key-password
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Company"
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=info@mail.nl
```

However I get this response:

```
Connection could not be established with host smtp.sendgrid.net [Operation timed out #60]
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

I have followed the docs but this is not working!

https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/integrating_with_the_smtp_api.html

Please help me out.

Comment: Changing username to `MAIL_USERNAME=apikey` does not work.

Comment: have you found a solution yet? I am attempting to use Sendgrid also in a Laravel 5.8 application and I am getting `Authentication required` message.

Answer (score 0):

I was similarly having trouble.

As you noted, you need this in your `.env`:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=apikey
MAIL_PASSWORD=SG.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

1. Make sure you're usign the correct `.env` for whatever environment you're testing (local, staging, production).
2. Check that you've verified your domain DNS: https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/sender_auth
3. Also if you've recently created the SendGrid account, I think you're required to click the confirmation email to prove that you own the email address (before sending will work).

See Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mail